# Iconset Unicode emoticons (ios7, whatsapp)?

Tags: ios, unicode, icons, emoticons

I notice a lot of applications use the same emoticon set. I guess that they use unicode characters to represent the values. It looks like there is a generic set of images used to display them.

Does anyone know where to find this list (unicode code + emoticon image?)?

The images I refer to: (http://news.en.softonic.com/new-emoticons-added-to-whatsapp-for-android-1)

EDIT: I found the references to the unicode here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found a list here. I think it is a complete list.

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Answer (score 2):

The [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org) is available on the Web, and this is the authoritative source on what characters there are in Unicode. The Standard gets updated, often with many new characters added, at irregular intervals.